# Is there any way to get settings value of another snippet in shopify?

Tags: shopify

I have made a block and snippet files for each item in the block.```

````
{% for block in section.blocks %}
<div {{ block.shopify_attributes }}>
    {% case block.type %} 
        {% when 'cart_header' %} 
        {% include 'cart_header' %}         
        {% when 'Countdown_Timer' %}
        {% include 'Countdown_Timer' %}         
        {% when 'Announcement_Bar' %} 
        {% include 'Announcement_Bar' %}   
        {% when 'Free_Shipping_Bar' %} 
        {% include 'Free_Shipping_Bar'%} 
    {% endcase %}
</div>
{% endfor %}```
````

Is there any way or trick that I can get block.settings.xxx value of cart_header on countdown_timer snippet file?

Comment: put that setting to theme general setting, so any file can use it

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am sorry but settings should be in section files. Any way you think? Thanks in advance